# 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, sed, gatsby

I'm using gatsby mate portfolio but recent local development shows error when I run `npm start`:

```
'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-mate@2.5.1 fix-medium-plugin: `sed -i' ' 's//latest//g' ./node_modules/gatsby-source-medium/gatsby-node.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-mate@2.5.1 fix-medium-plugin script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It seems that it's not properly escaping `s //`

Here's `package.json` copy of the line it specified:

```
  "name": "gatsby-starter-mate",
  "version": "2.5.1",
  "description": "Gatsby v2 starter to create a top notch portfolio!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "fix-medium-plugin": "sed -i' ' 's/\/latest//g' ./node_modules/gatsby-source-medium/gatsby-node.js",
  "prepare": "npm run fix-medium-plugin && gatsby clean",
   "build": "npm run prepare && gatsby build",
   "develop": "npm run prepare && gatsby develop",
   "start": "npm run develop",
   "serve": "npm run build && gatsby serve -p 9000",
   "lint": "eslint ./src",
   "setup": "node ./bin/setup.js",
   "e2e:open": "cypress open",
   "e2e:ci": "DETERMINISTIC=true start-server-and-test serve http://localhost:9000 'percy exec -- cypress run'"
  },
```

Comment: Well `sed` is a Unix program, it won't be on Windows unless you specifically added it with MinGW or something along these lines.

Comment: Why conclude that it's improper escaping? If it can't find the command, the arguments become irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is a Unix command. You're likely within powershell in VSCode, you can still use this Gatsby starter you'll just need to run `npm start` within a unix terminal.

You can install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) path into your gatsby directory and enter `npm start` there and it will run successfully.

I have created a new gatsby project using this *mate* starter reached the same problem you are having and then confirmed with the creator of *mate* that there are no alternative solutions at this time other than running it via a unix terminal. Here is a [link](https://github.com/EmaSuriano/gatsby-starter-mate/commit/5e732197ad169bf2a4dc0f46f8faeecbedb2250e#comments) to the commit that occured on the 21st October 2019 that caused this problem for you and there you will find EmaSuriano's solution to your problem :)

Comment: thanks for comprehensive answer. I did found the commit that cause the problem yesterday and I've tried using the older version. but you suggestion using cygwin is much better. :)

Comment: what do you mean install it the gatsby directory? the directory of the project or the directory where gatsby cli is installed

Comment: @Ramomex1 Sorry mate I simply mean you need to install "cygwin" just how you'd install any program. It's simply a terminal (alternative to powershell or the windows command line you use).

Once you have installed cygwin you will need to do "ls" (this lists the files within your current directory) then "cd" (change directory) to enter the folder you have your gatsby project in :) Then you can run "npm start" within the mate starter directory to run it.  

Using cygwin means that the "sed" command within the package.json script will run without error since "sed" isn't a windows command :)